# How to set the Background image in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I need to set the Background image in visualforce page. Please helpme

Comment: Please do not simply ask the community to do your homework for you; always include details and samples of what you have already tried and explain where you are stuck. In this instance, I'd recommend starting with CSS applied to the form, or perhaps to a wrapping div.

Comment: Background image of which part you want to change? Please explain.

Comment: Hi, Whole Background that page

Comment: Visualforce renders a HTML page, for which you can use inline style mark up  or CSS (.. which I would advise). Was that not clear to you from the visualforce documentation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can add an image in the background. Hope this will help.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Contact" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif");
        background-repeat:repeat;
    }
</style>
</apex:page>
```

**Updated Solution**

Solution updated to include the background image.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Contact" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif");
            background-repeat:repeat;
        }
        input[type="text"] {
            background: transparent;
            border:1px solid #000;
        }        
    </style>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.LastName}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi Saroj Bera, Its working better, But this image is not showing background of input values. my requirement is Display throughout page and(background of fields also shown)  .

Comment: @pgpg please check my updated solution. Hope this will help.

Comment: Its working Fine.ThankYou very much Saroj Bera

Comment: @pgpg Can you please mark it as answer.